# UIButton title refresh after UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I have a button with title **Fun** whitch is set from the storyboard

In viewDidLoad I change the title

```
self.catBut.titleLabel.text = @"Random";
```

And then when another button is click

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title alert" message:@"Alert message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
```

But after the alert shows up the title of the button change back to **Fun**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.h file keep this

```
@property(non atomic,strong)IBOutlet UIButton *catBut;
```

use this for change the button title

```
[self.catBut setTitle:@"Random" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

use `UIAlertViewDelegate` Method

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title alert" message:@"Alert message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
alert.tag==100; //if u used multiple alert in your VC, use to identify the Tag
  [alert show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex    
{
if(alertView.tag==100)
{
 [self.catBut setTitle:@"Random" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
 }
else
  {
   // anotehr mthod optiobns
 }
 }
```

Comment: after Ok is triggered the button is again Fun

Comment: you need to change the button title is "FUN" when u hit the alert view button , correct, or any other thing u need to modify

Comment: no, the button title is change in viewDidLoad. And reseted after alert but dont want to reset the value. The button have to stay Random

Comment: I think my modify answer is fine for your ?, will u need any modification, i change my answer for u

Comment: setTitle do the job without UIAlertViewDelegate